# Swift: cannot call async func from normal func?

Tags: swift, asynchronous

In Swift 5.5:

Following Swift Code will get compiler error: "async call in a function that does not support concurrency".

```swift
// Swift
func hi() async {
    print("hi")
}

func callAsyncHi() {
    hi()
}
```

In Javascript, await is only valid in async function, but calling an async func from a normal func is valid. So following Javascript Code prints "hi" asynchronously.

```js
// Javascript
async function hi() {
    console.log("hi")
}

function callAsyncHi() {
    hi()
}

callAsyncHi()
```

I also found an async func cannot be called without **await** or **async let**.
Why Swift is designed in this way?

Comment: Use `await hi()` to invoke that async function. You can find reasons on why you write `await` when invoking async function here: https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Concurrency.html

Comment: because default swift behavior is not async, `async/await` is new and it suspend the following codes. so when to call async func in non-async function, you need put it in a `Task` https://www.advancedswift.com/async-await/#call-async-function-from-non-async-code

Answer (score 9):

You can invoke async function from normal function by wrapping the asynchronous call inside a task:

```swift
func hi() async {
    print("hi")
}

func callAsyncHi() {
    let task = Task {
        await hi()
    }
}
```

This is similar to how you can invoke async methods in java script from synchrnous context, key difference being in Swift you have to explicitly specify it and inside `Task` you can invoke more than one async methods.

There are certain reasons behind a design like this. Key reason being in Swift all async methods are associated with tasks and support [cooperative cancellation](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Concurrency.html).

> Swift concurrency uses a cooperative cancellation model. Each task checks whether it has been canceled at the appropriate points in its execution, and responds to cancellation in whatever way is appropriate.

By requiring `async` keyword Swift keeps track of the dependency chain of async calls and propagates cancellation event when it occurs (While as far as I know promises in JS doesn't support cancellation of promises). In the above code, you can invoke cancellation on `task` variable by keeping track of it.

Now the second reason, more important in my opinion, is by requiring explicit invocation this makes it easier to review code as I have to check if cancellation for such invocations are properly handled while in case of JS it is harder to pinpoint such misuse.

Answer (score -2):

- An async function from Javascript returns a **Promise**.
- An async function from C# returns a **Task**.

We pass Promises/Tasks around freely and do many things.

But an async function from Swift returns **???**.

**???** is hidden. I cannot even print its type.

```swift
// swift compiler error: Expression is 'async' but is not marked with 'await'
func callAsyncHi() {
  Task {
    async let tmp = hi()
    print(Mirror(reflecting: tmp).subjectType)
    await tmp
  }
}
```

I guess there is no **???**. So we have to use async func with **await**.

Comment: After reading https://forums.swift.org/t/se-0296-async-await/42605 . I found my guess is correct. There is no Future/Promise type in async/await for better compiler optimization. But I do need them... I will stick to Google/Promises. I don't like async keyword to pollute other func.